# pouchDB query return empty object when used in an exported Async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb

Simply put, I have main.js and query.js also imported query.js's database() Async function into main.js

In main.js - I implemented setInterval based Async function that call the imported database() function with await keyword for polling the data.

Once data captured, setInterval based Async function, console.log the captured data.

Now the case is when I call the database() from main.js, Pouchdb return { docs: [] } but when I call database() from query.js directly, it return all documents.

Why does Pouchdb behaves that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed by moving database folder into build folder. I've forgotten that Rollup using build folder to locate resources.